# Unity & StructureMap

Tags: structuremap, unity-container

Are there equivalent for StructureMap of this in Unity:

```
ServiceLocator.Current.GetAllInstances<IT>
```

Trying to follow [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/02/17/use-bootstrapper-in-your-asp-net-mvc-application-and-reduce-code-smell.aspx) little pattern...

Comment: Your link is dead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances();

see http://structuremap.sourceforge.net/RetrievingServices.htm#section3
for more details

Comment: I understood what was my problem. Thanks for "effort". :)